# How I do cross reference a linked FK database table in Anylogic?

Tags: database, nullpointerexception, foreign-keys, anylogic

Lets say i have a few tables that are linked via a foreign key. The Orders table was used to generate Agents to rep the orders. In the Orders table there is field called tub_name which is the key (FK) to tubular table. The tubular table has a field called od which i want to name as a parameter in the Order agent (based on the Orders tub_name value). Visually, The orders Table:
[image: orders Table]

Linked tubulars table:
[image: Linked tubulars table]

I want to add the corresponding "od" value in the linked tubulars table to my Order agent. The expression for the new parameter (od) typically looks like (as generated either by the DBQ wizard or the properties dialogue):

```js
(double) selectFrom(tubulars)
 .where(tubulars.tubular_key.eq(tubName))
 .firstResult(tubulars.od)
```

When i run this i get a null pointer error :
[image: Anylogic Error]

Can you tell me what i am doing wrong? Or how do you access data from another table with a matched/linked field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL code looks fine. I suspect the NPE comes from you trying to use `tubName` which is likely not initialized in your source object where you create the agent.

Try creating the agents without filling parameters and fill them manually in the "on enter" code field of your source element. If there is a param `tubName`, you can fill it calling `agent.set_tubName(SQL code getting the tub_name value)`

Then do the same to fill your `od` parameter

Comment: Thanks!.  Everything i did = NPE, exc a state chart inside the Orders and in the entry point set_param(SQL) to assign values to the para. BUT I still have a prob. From Orders, Tubular agents are called, and i need to pass a correct value for the tubular key when the Tubular agent executes. Everything throws an NPE. I can put a fixed string, and it will ref the table vals correctly, but i cannot seem to transfer the right key to the Tubular Agent from orders. I tried using a variable in main from inside where tubular is generated from Orders. But the NPE persists. Can you suggest something? Thx

Comment: Can you put this into a new question with some additional description & screenshots, hard to follow here :-)

Comment: Ok. I had to remove all the explanation and abbreviate everything as i was down to the max characters.

Comment: Hence put it in a new question. Best practice anyway, SOF questions should not become discussions that meander but be focussed on 1 specific issue to solve :-) (so it is always easy for future users with similar specific probs)

Comment: Ok, Ill post it in a day, im experimenting with a few things so i can make a better post.